# Reserve a few special primary keys (where auto_increment is enabled)

Tags: mysql

Assuming a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

I would like to "reserve" a few id's if possible. From what I've tested so far, it throws off the auto_increment. Is there away to insert a value with an id of 10, and still have the auto_increment insert records for 1-9, and continue to 11?

using:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`table` (`id`,`value`) VALUES(10, 'this is a special row');
```

This will insert the correct row in the table, however throws off the auto_increment so that nothing less than 10 will be used. This would be a problem for me as I would like to reserve several keys, some that are very high values.

I have tried altering the table after inserting a special key re-setting the auto_increment value back to 1, but this does not seem to work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why ? If you want specific identifiers, create another field and use it for that. An autoincremented field is not done for "logical values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work like that. The AUTO_INCREMENT value will be larger than the highest value already in the table, it won't "fill in" missing id values that are less than the highest value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html